# How to open window from xaml without code-behind

Tags: wpf, button

I have other-window.xaml file and trying to open this from window.xaml on button click. How did it without code-behind?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just because you have no code-behind does not mean your code is of a high quality. Are you trying to ensure it can be unit tested? designed via Expression Blend? Are you following MVVM?

Comment: I am following MVVM. My code-behind in C#, view model and program model in F#. It seems to me wrong create a View element(such as window) in code-behind and set its properties from code-behind when all other View components in xaml-files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the window as a [non-shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) resource and write an [`Interactivity`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) `TriggerAction` that resolves the resource and calls `Show` on the window. That action can then be used in the combination with an `Interactivity` `EventTrigger` on `Click`.

Comment: +1 Yep - basically it's a whole heck of a lot of work. Just write a bit of code-behind, it really does not harm!

Comment: @ColinE: Wouldn't consider it that much work, just one new class with about three lines of imperative code.

Comment: Not bad, It would be helpful to see a simple example

Comment: @psct: Actually it's a bit more complicated, you would need an IServiceProvider to resolve a StaticResource reference, and you cannot create a reference directly because it will be resolved once and when the window is closed you cannot reopen it so you get an exception. Right now i cannot investigate this further but i may try later.